# Ruby unix date incorrect

Tags: ruby, unix

I have the following Unix timestamp: `1478698378000`

And I'm trying to show this as a datetime in Ruby, e.g.

```
<%= Time.at(@timestamp).to_datetime %>
```

Which should be returning a date of: `Wed, 09 Nov 2016 13:32:58 GMT` but the above code actually returns a date of: `48828-02-01T13:26:40+00:00` **Ignore formatting!**

As you can see it thinks that timestamp is 2nd Feb 48828 13:26:40.

Why is the datetime coming out completely incorrect and the year so far into the future like that? Checking the timestamp on http://www.epochconverter.com/ reveals the timestamp to be correct, so it's Ruby that's returning it incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Time.at` expects seconds as an argument and your timestamp is an amount of milliseconds. See [documentation on Time.at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-c-at)

Comment: Ah `<%= Time.at(( @crash.timestamp / 1000 )).to_datetime %>` solves it!

Comment: Upvoted just for the sake of fairness. The OP had to accept this answer rather than re-posting it from his own name.

Answer (score 1):

Why won’t you check the unix timestamp correctness against “Fashion Week Magazine” or “Cosmopolitan” Site?

Unix timestamp is an amount of seconds lasted since 1970-01-01 UTC:

```
date --date='@1478698378000'
mar feb  1 14:26:40 CET 48828
```

BTW, dropping last three zeroes gives you back what you’ve expected:

```
date --date='@1478698378'
mié nov  9 14:32:58 CET 2016
```